# Не меняется цвет <shape/> при первом старте активити

Tags: android, activity

В drawable лежит простенький shape:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    android:shape="rectangle"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="15dp"/>
    <solid android:color="#ffcd7821"/>
</shape>
```

Он является бекграундом для RelativeLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                tools:context=".MainActivity"
                android:background="@drawable/shape">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Нужно программно изменить цвет shape при старте актвити. Делаю это так:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        GradientDrawable gd = (GradientDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shape);
        gd.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    }
```

Цвет при старте активити не меняется. Но меняется при рестарте активити.

Вопросы:
Почему не меняется цвет shape при старте??
Как сделать чтобы shape изменил цвет при первом старте активити??

Answer (score 3):

Используйте в методе onStart():

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        GradientDrawable gd = (GradientDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shape);
        gd.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

До меня дошло.
Все дело в том, что при первом запуске, активити получал сперва `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`
с значением
`solid android:color="#ffcd7821"`
и последующие изменения шейпа в него не попадали.

Необходимо сперва выполнить изменения в shape, а затем вгружать контент.
Если сделать так, то все работает:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        GradientDrawable gd = (GradientDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shape);
        gd.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
```

Comment: Признаюсь честно, удивлен. Не думал что ресурсы в xml можно редактировать в процессе работы программы.

Answer (score 0):

Не понял что вы хотите, но видать андроид того же мнения.
Объясню что вы делаете: формируете новый объект на основе xml ресурса и меняете в нем цвет. Зачем вам менять цвет, если вы не применяете этот объект далее?

Как я понимаю, вам нужно поменять цвет фона активности?
Тогда просто вызовите метод setBackgraund для корневой view или по id для указанной RelativeLayout.

Хотите поменять цвет в самом ресурсе? Увы, xml ресурсы не изменяемы из кода.